Trying to log in to sharepoint.com yet failing
I'm logged in into my MS account at the Edge browser. Now I've done the same at Chrome browser. Yet, I fail to log into sharepoint.com (OneDrive) of MS at the Chrome browser, see the shot:  https://prnt.sc/dv2Z3c49vpmk
Why is that ? Any way out ?

Lately, I've found some Microsoft sites require the same PC login name used to create an account (three factor authentication). For example, with a Hotmail (Outlook) account, I could not log in with Thunderbird email client on another PC (where the account name differed), until T'bird put up a notice allowing for using a different PC account name. Please let me know if that's the case, and I'll make it a full answer.

@DrMoishePippik, I do not think this being the case. The PC is the same, I try to switch to another browser though. Login to microsoft.com is done - https://prnt.sc/e6bcoEUHVO2g but when trying to sharepoint.com with the same login - failure! https://prnt.sc/dv2Z3c49vpmk
